# Capture short or long version numbers in a string using RegEx

Tags: regex, groovy

```
my_input_string = "something Apache/2.3.4 more stuff PHP/4.5.6 other stuff"
```

The output I want to capture is 2.3.4 (it should look for `'Apache/'` and grab the version after that. The version number may be shorter or longer like 2.3 or 2.3.4.5 (any group of numbers with dots in between). I've seen other articles but closest one has 3 outputs. I just want one.

I've been searching Google and using RegEx101.com and RegExr.com but kinda trial and error.

I saw this: `Apache\/(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)$` but it seems to output 3 separate outputs and it only works with 2 and 3 digits not 4. I tried to change the parenthesis but no luck.

My final result will be in a Groovy script.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

Edit: It now captures one digit, then a group of repeating digits and ".", where the group may have zero or more such characters:

```
​def my_input_string = "something Apache/2.3.4 more stuff PHP/4.5.6 other stuff"
def regex = /.*Apache\/(\d[\d\.]*) .*/
def matcher = (my_input_string =~ regex)
println matcher[0][1]​
```

Comment: this works! thanks. I'm new to groovy and reading "Groovy in Action" book but can you or someone explain what matcher[0][1] does? As far as I know it grabs the first and second item in a array or list but that doesn't make sense to me yet.

Comment: That is a separate question, but in brief, the =~ operation returns a Matcher object. This is in java.util.regex.Matcher, and is augmented with Groovy methods (i.e. the GDK). Examples are here: http://mrhaki.blogspot.ca/2009/09/groovy-goodness-matchers-for-regular.html

Comment: [0][1] doesn't get the first and second element. It's usually used for a multidimensional array, so you could say it would get row 0, column 1. However, in this case, it doesn't, but delegates to the [getAt method of matcher](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#getAt(int)). Ps, I hope you're reading the Second Edition, it's much more up to date than the first version.